# Bridge Pattern vs Dependency Injection

Tags: design-patterns

What are differences between Bridge Pattern and Dependency Injection?

For the both patterns we have an abstract class with implementation of another abstraction. There is the Bridge Pattern UML diagramm below.

[image]

Comment: I disagree with those claiming DI isn't a design pattern. Few would argue MVC isn't a design pattern, and it also has multiple implementation patterns.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK Dependency Injection is *not a design pattern* but a *design guideline* defined in the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

So *Bridge pattern* ***uses*** dependency injection in it to achieve the required polymorphic behavior where the `DrawingAPI` is being injected in the constructor to decouple the `Shape` from the concrete implementation of API.

Snippet from the example of [Bridge Pattern of Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern)

```
protected Shape(DrawingAPI drawingAPI){
      this.drawingAPI = drawingAPI;
}
```

Bridge Pattern - *A design pattern*

Dependency Injection - *Design guideline or principle*

Comment: I agree what you said but when I read the definition from Wiki, it said "dependency injection is a software design pattern that implements inversion of control for software libraries" so do you think the term "design pattern" is wrong or it would be correct in a kind of view?

Comment: @fmchan IMHO dependency injection is a principle rather than a design pattern. It forms the core of many GoF design patterns and it is one of the fundamental principle of SOLID.

Comment: IMHO dependency injection isn't a perfect "Bridge Pattern", because people who used it most often doesn't define the interface at all, instead they just define a class/module which to me is more towards final implementation. There's no much switching of the implementation without changing interface idea in it.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I am wonder how you make sure with DI that `Shape` got expected `DrawingAPI` if you have multiple implementations of `DrawingAPI`? If you have multiple implementations in that case it will be collection.

Answer (score 7):

You can do Dependency Injection through several mechanisms.  The Bridge mechanism is only one of them.  Simple interface implementation is another.  Class-weaving and other dynamic tricks yet another.

Dependency Injection is a development/design technique, but not a pattern since it can be implemented in several ways.

Thinking a bit more about this, you could consider Dependency Injection a Software Architecture Pattern (but still not a design one), in the sense that it's a common way of addressing a series of Architectural concerns (testability, configurability, modularity, etc).

In other words, Dependency Injection could effectively be considered a Pattern, but in a different level:  Architecture, not Design.

Answer (score 4):

Many Design Patterns have similar UML diagrams.

The Bridge Pattern is completely different than Dependency Injection.

[Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) - A way to easily insert (and swap) dependencies in code either at runtime or compile time.

[Bridge Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) - A way to have an extra interface between different systems.  The Bridge is the communication layer between your code and the other system.  For example, the two most used Bridge Pattern implementations in Java are JDBC (which communicates with a database via a Driver Bridge) and Swing (which uses a Bridge to communicate with the Operating System's UI).  This lets the other system get swapped out or changed without affecting or changes the communication layer to your system.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that a Bridge also allows both sides on the bridge to evolve and change independently without affecting the other.  This is because the Bridge isolates both sides from each other.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the Bridge Pattern uses DI for the Implementor instantiation?

Comment: @Warlock yes I would say that. DI is a concept and not a design pattern in itself. There is nothing like pattern in it. DI is being used since ages even before GoF book was published. So I would say it is a guideline for writing loosely coupled code than a Design pattern.

Comment: @Warlock you can use DI for either side of the Bridge implementation instantiation but it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

The Bridge Pattern uses *[Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion)* to make the bridge work i.e. the Abstraction base class/interface depends on the Implementor interface.

Dependency Injection is the most often used implementation of the Dependency Inversion Principle.

Comment: I disagree, Dependency Injection is the implementation of IOC (inversion of control). I agree with the first part about Bridge.

Answer (score 1):

For me these are two patterns with different intentions. The bridge pattern is used to avoid the proliferation of subclasses that inheritance mechanisms would eventually lead to. So, if you have, say, 2 orthogonal responsibilities, instead of creating 2**2 subclasses, you make use of composition to combine these responsibilities, two by two, but it says nothing about how this combination will be made (i.e, it has no constructor or set injection, well, not  necessarily; it requires no interfaces, etc.). This composition can even be hardcoded!

Dependency injection, on the other hand is used to avoid coupling, by separating the creation of a dependency from its use. For this to be achieved, it demands the help from a third party: the injector. It also makes generous uses of interfaces. What do bridge pattern and DI have in common? Both make use of composition. No more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern book is mostly using similar implementation, ex. if it's not subclass object, then it's passing another object into it. So in the end I realized that the pattern book is not about how you write the implementation code, ex. do you use a class or dependency injection?

The pattern is more about a context, or simply a story, why you design such schema to deliver the product. Although the implementation could be similar from pattern to pattern, the pattern's birth and its intrinsic idea is much more important here.

In short, if you are passing an object into a class's constructor, it doesn't really mean if you are using any pattern at all. But if the process is designed for some purpose, then you might be surprised that you might find a name in the pattern book.

From Wiki,

> In software engineering, a software design pattern is a general, reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design. It is not a finished design that can be transformed directly into source or machine code. Rather, it is a description or template for how to solve a problem that can be used in many different situations. Design patterns are formalized best practices that the programmer can use to solve common problems when designing an application or system.